# Add a fitted box to a multiline equation

Tags: math-mode, formatting, boxes, empheq

I am trying to draw a fitted box around some equations. However, I was not able to control the width of the box. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,empheq}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Higher Order Equations}
\begin{itemize}
\item Must make into a system of first-order equations to use ODE solvers
\item Nonlinear is OK!
\item Pendulum example:
\end{itemize}
\scriptsize
\begin{flalign*}
&\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{L}sin(\theta)=0&\\
&\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{L}sin(\theta)&\\
&\text{let } \dot{\theta} = \gamma&\\
&\dot{\gamma}=-\dfrac{g}{L}sin(\theta)&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{flalign*}
&\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{bmatrix}\theta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}&\\
&\dfrac{d\overrightarrow{x}}{dt} =  \begin{bmatrix}\dot{\theta}\\\dot{\gamma}\end{bmatrix}&
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\normalsize
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the framed box fit its content one needs to measure the contents width first. In this case I simply assigned the content to measure to box register 0, i.e. `\setbox0=\hbox{...}` and retrieve its width from `\wd0`. So, your box macro will be defined as

```
\newcommand*\WideFittedFramebox[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}%
  \framebox[\the\wd0]{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}%
}
```

Note that I changed its name and that `\framebox` now is employed to create the frame and not `\fbox` as the `\framebox` command takes an optional argument that sets the width. (Otherwise one would need to `\fbox{\parbox{\the\wd0}{...}}`.)

Additionally, I adjusted the markup of the code

- using `\scriptsize` inside a group instead of `\scriptsize...\normalsize`,
- the `gather` environment together with the `fleqn` option instead of the `flalign` enviroment with empty columns,
- `\sin...` instead of plain `sin...` and
- by nesting the equation blocks properly inside the `subequations` environment.

The complete code then is

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,empheq}

\newcommand*\WideFittedFramebox[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}
  \framebox[\the\wd0]{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Higher Order Equations}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Must make into a system of first-order equations to use ODE solvers
  \item Nonlinear is OK!
  \item Pendulum example:
\end{itemize}

\begingroup \scriptsize
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{gather*}
    \ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{L}\sin(\theta)=0\\
    \ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{L}\sin(\theta)\\
    \text{let }\dot{\theta}=\gamma\\
    \dot{\gamma}=-\dfrac{g}{L}\sin(\theta)
  \end{gather*}
  \begin{empheq}[box=\WideFittedFramebox]{gather*}
    \overrightarrow{x}=\begin{bmatrix}\theta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}\\
    \dfrac{d\overrightarrow{x}}{dt}=\begin{bmatrix}\dot{\theta}\\\dot{\gamma}\end{bmatrix}
  \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\endgroup
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Is there an alternative to fleqn? fleqn would flush all my equations to the left.

Comment: @MAS -- Yes, there is the `fleqn` environment of the `nccmath` package (that allows flushleft display math locally), but there is some incopatibility problem (the equations in the framed block just disappear) that I can't localize/fix quickly. You could ask a follow-up question on this.

Comment: `scriptsize` environment? There's no such thing. It works by mere fortune. `\scriptsize` is a font switch, so use it inside a group to restrict its scope.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- I can't prove it, but it actually does exist ;) And the code compiles without any `\endscriptsize` undefined errors.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- I don't know if the following source is trustworthy, but here is a first clue: https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Textgr%C3%B6%C3%9Fen, http://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/

Comment: @Ruben Just because something doesn't produce errors, it doesn't mean that it is correct :-) And I'm sure you know that those Wiki-things cannot be 100% trusted.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- yes... So I rollback to the original markup, I guess.